# sybase external login for proxy table

Tags: remote-server, sybase-ase15

Dears,
kindly note I have created an external login and a remote login as following:
sp_addremotelogin remoteserver,locallogin1, remotelogin1
sp_addexternallogin remoteserver,locallogin1, remotelogin1

and I log in by user locallogin1 to the localserver to the database localdb and try to create proxy table from remotedb1 on remoteserver but still get the login failed error, any body know why??

kindly note  there is localuser1 aliased to locallogin1 , i.e there is no user 'locallogin1' (direct mapping) on the database localdb where I try to create proxy table, rather there is a user localuser1 is alias to locallogin1, is this related to the problem??

please advice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dears,
kindly note that the problem is solved, the case was the password, the passwords for local login and remote login are different, so I add the remote password to sp_addexternallogin as follow: 
 exec sp_addexternlogin [remoteserver], [locallogin], [remotelogin],  [remotepassword]

and every thing is well

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are mixing some things up.For creating a proxy table, you do not need a 'remote login' as created by sp_remotelogin. You need the external login however, which should mao to an actual login in the remote server.

For more advice, you should post the exact steps taken plus the error output.

Comment: I added remoteserver using sp_addserver

server name I used in sp_addserver exactly the same as its name in my local interfaces file.

but the password for locallogin1 on localserver not the same as the password for remotelogin1 on remoteserver

Comment: let me add this: I can log in directly to remoteserver using remotelogin1 and that password, and can log in directly to localserver using locallogin1 and his login name is different from remotelogin name and also the passwords, is this the case????

Comment: You can use tgat for old-style remote procedure calls